# Assembling multiple beamer slide decks into "book" with "chapters" and TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, page-numbering, chapters

I have a number of related beamer slide decks that I'd like to print as a bound handout "book".

My file layout is as follows:

A general include file (include.tex) used by most other files:

```
\documentclass[12pt,table,english,t,compress]{beamer}
\author{...}
% \usepackage defintions

\title{...}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

% Various color and command definitions
```

Then, for each of my slide decks, I have a pair of files (deck_1.tex, deck_1_slides.tex) structured as follows:

```
% deck_1.tex

\input{include.tex}

\begin{document}

\input{deck_1_slides.tex}

\end{document}
```

And:

```
% deck_1_slides.tex

\subtitle{Deck 1 subtitle}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}

    %\tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Section A}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{XXX} ... \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{YYY} ... \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{ZZZ} ... \end{frame}

\section{Section B}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{AAA} ... \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{BBB} ... \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{CCC} ... \end{frame}

...
```

The above set up works fine for producing the individual slide decks. I get the conventional numbering "Page-N/Total-pages" on each slide, and I have Section TOCs that appear at the start of each section. All well and good.

However, I am stuck when it comes to producing the "book" version of the slides.
What I would like to do is this:

1. Treat each slide deck as a numbered chapter. When producing the handout version, make the running number at the bottom of each slide "Chapter-number / slide-number" (i.e., drop the "Total slides").
2. Change the Section TOC's in each slide deck to be just the "Section Title" or, perhaps the "Chapter Title" (i.e., the \subtitle in the decks above) plus the "Section Title".
3. Produce a "Grand TOC" at the start of the "book", which consists of just the "Chapter" titles and "Section" titles. I'd like the Grand TOC to include the "Chapter-number / slide-number" page numbering used in the individual decks.
4. **Update**: I realize that there is another point that I had in mind that I did not make explicit in my original formulation. In the grand TOC I'd like to see numbering of the form Chapter.Section.

For example, the Chapter.Section numbering in the Grant TOC might look like this:

```
1    Deck 1 title                   1-nn
1.1  Deck 1 Section 1 title         1-nn
1.2  Deck 1 Section 2 title         1-nn
1.3  Deck 1 Section 3 title         1-nn
2    Deck 2 title                   2-nn
2.1  Deck 2 Section 1 title         2-nn
2.2  Deck 2 Section 2 title         2-nn
```

("nn" are frame numbers)

Analogously, in the Deck TOCs I'd like to have something like this (here, for Deck 2)

```
2    Deck 2 title                   2-nn
2.1  Deck 2 Section 1 title         2-nn
2.2  Deck 2 Section 2 title         2-nn
```

I'm assuming all of the above is possible, since LaTeX is fairly flexible (I'm a relative newbie), but I'm a little lost trying to achieve the book version with the features described above (especially 1 and 3). Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) The `pgfpages` package might help you. Check [this link](http://www.offerman.com/Linux_Unix/LaTeX_Beamer/).

Comment: @masu: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how pgfpages helps with my questions. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't really have any time for this right now, but I've just started a bounty. :)

Comment: Not sure if it helps you but [`a-lecture`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/examples/a-lecture) folder  in your `LaTeX` distribution contains a nice example mixing a [`beamer`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/examples/a-lecture/beamerexample-lecture-beamer-version.tex) presentation and its [printed (book)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/examples/a-lecture/beamerexample-lecture-print-version.tex) version. (links point to CTAN corresponding folder and files)

Comment: I have two questions regarding the example: (1) I think that `\input{lsp_include.tex}` should be `\input{include.tex}`, where `\input{include.tex}` is your first code snippet. (2) If I compile it I have no running number at the bottom. Do you use a specific outer theme (`infolines` for example)?

Comment: @crixstox: You were right. I meant "include.tex". I edited the question. Regarding (2), yes, I'm doing some stuff to get running numbers at the foot of the slide. I omitted that to keep the description simple.

Comment: @Ignasi: Thanks for the pointer. It doesn't directly help with my questions, but I think there's useful stuff there that I will want to use sometime in the future.

Comment: @mtk: Is it ok for you if I edit your question changing "chapter" to "part". I think this would clarify the question even further.

Comment: @crixstox: I'd hold off on changing "chapter" to "part". The thing is, "Chapter" describes what I really had in mind, in terms of a "book", whereas "part" is more an implementation details (if we're talking about LaTeX/Beamer parts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by the question-opener in the comments to my first answer, here a different approach: Change `section` to `subsection` and include the different decks a sections.

- No changes in `deck_n.tex`.
- Replace `\section` by `\subsection` in `deck_n_slides.tex`.
- To specify the appearance of the "Deck TOC" use the options for for `\tableofcontents`. (e.g. use `\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=hide,subsection=show]` in `deck_n_slides.tex`).

Replace `include.tex` with

```
\documentclass[12pt,table,english,t,compress]{beamer}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\title{Title}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\makeatletter
    \let\origSubsection\subsection
    \def\subsection#1{\stepcounter{framenumber} \origSubsection[#1]{#1 \hfill \ \arabic{section} -- \arabic{framenumber}} \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
    \let\origSection\section
    \def\section#1{\setcounter{framenumber}{1} \origSection[#1]{#1 \hfill \ \arabic{section} -- \arabic{framenumber}} \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sectionnumber}[1]{\setcounter{section}{#1} \addtocounter{section}{-1}}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber~\inserttocsection}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber~\inserttocsubsection\\}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox
    {%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertsectionnumber{} -- \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

For the collection of all slides you can use then `handout.tex` given as follows

```
% handout.tex

\input{include.tex}
\date{yyyy-mm-dd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Grand TOC}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\input{deck_1_slides.tex}
\input{deck_2_slides.tex}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I leave my original answer. Some possible changes according to the edit in the question are listed below. A little piece to cover all the details of the question is still missing and explained in the last section.

---

## Original  answer

I tried to find a solution within the following design principles:

1. No changes in the files `include.tex`, `deck_1.tex`, `deck_1_slides.tex`, such that the individual slide sets remain unchanged.
2. Usage of high-level commands, when possible.
3. Usage of as few additional packages as possible. In my solution only [`nameref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref) is needed.

This led to the following solution (the full code and the image of the "Grand TOC" are posted below):

- The changes are all made in a main file named `handout.tex`, there the slide files (e.g. `deck_1_slide.tex`) are loaded with included with `input`
- I use the `part` option of `\tableofcontents` in the `beamer` class. Therefore I redifined `\subtitle`

  ```
  \let\origSubtitle\subtitle
  \renewcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
      \origSubtitle{#1}%
      \stepcounter{chapter} \part{\thechapter}%
      \labelname{#1} \label{chapter:\thechapter}}
  ```
- To change the numbering style I adjusted the beamertemplate `footline`. (In the example code below I adapted it to the outer theme `infolines`.)
- Since this numbering style can not be used at the beginning for the "Grand TOC" `footline``is changed locally once more.
- To get the desired numbering in the table of contents I used the short sectiontitle ability. Hence the redefinition of `\section`

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \let\origSection\section
  \def\section#1{\stepcounter{framenumber} \origSection[#1]{#1 \dotfill \ \insertpartnumber{} / \arabic{framenumber}} \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
  \makeatother
  ```
- Finally I define a new command `\grandtoc` which take the "part"-number as input, to set the "Grand TOC".

Full code (`deck_2.tex` and `deck_2_slides.tex` have the same form as there counterparts `deck_1.tex` and `deck_1_slides.tex`):

```
% handout.tex

\input{include.tex}

% Outher theme to have running numbers at the bottom
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\institute{Institute}
\date{yyyy-mm-dd}

\usepackage{nameref} % new package

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelname}[1]{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{chapter}

% redefinition fo subtitle
\let\origSubtitle\subtitle
\renewcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \origSubtitle{#1}%
    \stepcounter{chapter} \part{\thechapter}%
    \labelname{#1} \label{chapter:\thechapter}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertpartnumber{} / \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}

% redinition of section
\makeatletter
\let\origSection\section
\def\section#1{\stepcounter{framenumber} \origSection[#1]{#1 \dotfill \ \insertpartnumber{} / \arabic{framenumber}} \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\grandtoc}[1]
{%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} \nameref{chapter:#1}}%
    \tableofcontents[part=#1,sectionsstyle=show,subsectionstyle=hide]%
}

\begin{document}

{
    \makeatletter
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%  
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Grand TOC}
        \grandtoc{1}
        \grandtoc{2}
    \end{frame}
}

\input{deck_1_slides.tex}
\input{deck_2_slides.tex}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following "Grand TOC":

[image: Grand TOC]

## Changes (to be made to answer the edited question)

To do not reset the framenumber for a new part delete the line `\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}`.

To reset the section number for each part include (following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65656/how-do-one-reset-the-section-numbers-in-beamer))

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{%
    \beamer@tocsectionnumber=0\relax
    \setcounter{section}{0}
}
\makeatother
```

**Attention:** You can only have one active `\AtBeginPart`. To reset the framenumber and the section number, merge them together.

To have (almost) the desired numbering style of the "Grand TOC" replace the redefinition of `\section` and the definition of `\grandtoc` with

```
% redinition of section
\makeatletter
\let\origSection\section
\def\section#1{\stepcounter{framenumber} \origSection[#1]{#1 \hfill \ \insertpartnumber{} -- \arabic{framenumber}} \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\grandtoc}[1]
{%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} #1 \nameref{chapter:#1}}%
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{#1.\inserttocsectionnumber~\inserttocsection}
    \tableofcontents[part=#1,sectionsstyle=show,subsectionstyle=hide]%
}
```

To have the "Deck TOC" formatted accordingly do the following (in contrast to my design principles - but I have no other idea):

- Add `\newcommand{\grandtoc}[1]{\tableofcontents}` and `\renewcommand{\thepart}{0}` to the preamble of every `deck_n.tex`.
- Replace in every `deck_n_slides.tex` `\tableofcontents` with `\grandtoc{\thepart}`

With this two command the style of compiling a single deck will not be altered, but for the book, the "Deck TOC" is redefined.

With these changes the "Grand TOC" now looks as follows.

[image: new Grand Toc]

## What is still missing

For the TOC there is no framenumber shown for the start of the different parts. The main reason therefore is, that with my solution the part title is not stored in the `.toc`-file but typeset directly. To include really the parts into the `.toc`, one might use ideas from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tableofcontents-from-part-commands-in-beamer). However, I assume,that this would lead to major necessary changes in other parts of the solution presented. Additionally, the difficulty described above is the reason, why title of parts are not aligned properly.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you post the resulting Grand TOC that you see from your test?

Comment: @mtk: I edited my answer and attached an image of the "Grand TOC" like proposed.

Comment: thanks for posting the result. It confirms what I saw too. Your solution is impressive--it does I think the key points of what I explicitly asked, but I realize there was another point that was implicit. I should have made that point explicit too. In the TOC, I'm wanting to see Chapter.Section numbering on the LHS. I'll edit the main question to describe what I mean.

Comment: Hey @crixstox, that's pretty good! Thank you. Even without the last piece (page numbering on the "Chapter" entries in the TOC), it's probably workable for me, but I'll investigate your pointers as well. I have just one question: would the task have been easier if my "Chapters" had been "\section"s and my "Sections" had been \subsections" (and I dispensed with the use of "\subtitle"s to generate the TOC)? That would of course have been (is) an easy (sed) edit to my *_slide.tex source files.

Comment: @mtk: Yes, with this setting it would be a lot easier. I will post another answer for this case.

Comment: Thanks. It was only later that I worked out that things might have been better if I adopted the use of sections/subsection as my structuring device.