# In beamer, is there anyway to show table of contents for specific sections only?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm helping my student w/ her dissertation, and she wanted to include slides for all 3 chapters in 1 pdf (using beamer).

We were working on this, but when we created "outline for the presentation" for each chapter using the table of contents, there were sections from other chapters that showed up, which we didn't want to show yet. We originally thought about using \section* command, but then that section didn't pop up in the other outline for the other chapters.

Is there anyway to show table of contents for specific sections only (i.e. sections 1 thru 6 and ignore 7 thru 18)?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\tableofcontents[sections={<list of section ranges>}]`:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

% helper
\newcommand\oneSecOneFrame{%
  \section{Title}%
  \begin{frame} contents \end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[sections={1-3}]
\end{frame}

\oneSecOneFrame
\oneSecOneFrame
\oneSecOneFrame

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[sections={4-}]
\end{frame}
\oneSecOneFrame
\oneSecOneFrame
\oneSecOneFrame
\end{document}
```

[image]

Check its documentation in `beamer` User Guide v3.63, sec. 10.5 "Adding a Table of Contents", option `sections={<overlay specification>}` for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome! Is there anyway to reset the counter (I want something like 1. Title, 2. Title, 3.Title or both tableofcontents). If not, is there anyway to hide the numbers (so only Title shows up)?

Comment: Section numbers are hidden by default, and it's `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]` that makes them shown.

Comment: Or you can use `\part{title} \begin{frame} \tableofcontents \end{frame} \section...`. To reset `section` per part, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65661.